# How do I show all files in "open file" dialogs in OS X?

Tags: macos, finder

There are [various articles](http://ianlunn.co.uk/articles/quickly-showhide-hidden-files-mac-os-x-mavericks/) describing how to work around the bug in Finder that stops some files being shown. However, the workaround described does not solve the same bug in the "open file" dialog, which I gather is related to Finder. All "open file" dialogs in all applications on my instance of OS X still resolutely refuse to show all files.

How do I work around this? How do I show files in "open file" dialogs on OS X?

(This wouldn't be so bad if there were a file path box which I could use, but a separate bug is stopping that from being shown.)

Comment: which files? which app?

Comment: @Tetsujin any, it appears. Sublime Text. LightTable. Chrome. etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>

**Obviously.** Why didn't I think of that?